# get touchstart coordinate on current element

Tags: javascript, html

So I have an element that looks like this:

```
 ____________________________________
/                                    \
|                                    |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
+------------------------------------+
|                                    |
|                                    |
\____________________________________/
```

I have attached a touchstart listener to it, like this:

```
    other_options.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }, false);
```

What I want to do, and I've already looked through the values of 'e' but I can't find any value consistent enough (values don't seem right to me when I try them) to do what I want.

I know the size of those rows. I just want to be able to take the Y coordinate of where the touchstart event fired, being 0 the upper coordinate of the element. That way, Math.floor(y / ROW_SIZE) will give me the row the touchstart event was started on.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to access like this.

```
e.touches[0].clientX/clientY.
```

the number touchs and touch information can be access via e.touches.

Take look at this FAQ.

[How to get the  x/y coordinates in touch events ?](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-get-the-xy-coordinates-in-touch-events/)

here is the touch event [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).

By the way, events will return x/y coordinates relative to the window only. we can't changed that. what you can do this. `top= 0 - element.top; x= clientx-top.`

Comment: It's giving me a coordinate, but I'd like to have a relative coordinate (meaning y=0 when I hit the top of the element, it's actually giving me 161 probably because of margins). Is there any way I can at least know the real upper position so I can just substract and get a 0 at the top?

Comment: could you please create jsfiddle.

Comment: I'll give it a go, I haven't used it much

Comment: ok this will work, http://jsfiddle.net/A6LBz/ my goal is, when clicking at the top of the red element, I want to have a "0", not a 100 as it's showing now because of margins or whatever is moving the element. thanks for your time, by the way

Comment: oh, I didn't say this, but I would like to be able to do that without having to know the element is 95 pixels from the top (else I would just hardcode a -95)

Comment: yes, you have to subtract -95 for top so that you can get the value ?

Comment: So there's absolutely no way to do that automatically? The example I did there is fixed so a -95 is easy, it's just that having dynamic elements can really screw this methodology

Comment: Events will return x/y relative to the window only. we can changed that. what you can do this. `top= 0 - element.top; x= clientx-top.`

Comment: Alright. Could you please update your answer so we make it easier for everyone else to read? I'll up and accept when you do. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23272/discussion-between-balakrishnan-and-h4lc0n)

Answer (score 13):

It is better to use `getBoundingClientRect()` method to calculate top & left values of an element.

The above approach, `element.top`, may not give top & left values relative to the viewport if the element is inside another container.

So to calculate touch co-ordinates relative to the element, we can do as below.

```
var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
xCoordinate = event.touches[0].clientX - rect.left;
yCoordinate = event.touches[0].clientY - rect.top;
```

To find out more about `getBoundingClientRect()` method, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).